# Multiple mod_rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have successfully created my mod_rewrite rule to change all dynamic URLs on the top level of the site, but now i need to create a rule for a second level, and i think later down the line i might need a second, second level of rewrites.

At the moment i have this

```
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?subj=$1
```

And this helps to change /index.php?subj=home to /home as iut does for all other pages such as /contact /about /events and so on.

But now I have created sub pages under events and therefore need to change /events.php?event=event-name to /event-name. But when i add another rule it messes up the whole site. What i tried to do is this

```
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?subj=$1
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ event.php?event=$1
```

But that didnt work.

But on top of all that i want to redirect index.php and / (the root) to /home

Could anyone please show me the correct rules as I have searched around but I just can't seem to get it right.

Many thanks in advance :)

Cheers

UPDATE:
Thanks for all your help so far, ive tried everything but can't seem to get it right. As suggested by Ben I will give a bit more info on the URLs.
Right now the entire site is sitting in a sub-directory as for now its still under development, so for now it is in mydomain.com/newwebsite/event.phpevent=2
But the .htaccess file currently in the root folder of the development site so it is in /newwebsite directory. 
So the URL that i am trying to write would be mydomain.com/newwebsite/event/2

You notice it says '2' and that is simply the page/event id. further down the line it will not be the id but rather its title.

Comment: +1 I had all sorts of trouble with .htaccess files when I started, they can be quite confusing. Will see if I can answer your query :-)

Comment: @Ben Carey. Yeah, tell me about it, it can be confusing, thanks :)

Comment: I am trying all of these suggestions but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Update your question with the exact urls that you are trying to rewrite (you can leave out the domain name), and what you would like to rewrite them to. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing for the same condition twice, you need to differentiate the regex to test for a unique feature.

I would rewrite the file similar to this:

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Ignore existing files and directories
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

# Set the general first level rewrites
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php?subj=home [NC]
RewriteRule ^event/(.+)$ event.php?event=$1 [NC]
```

Or alternatively you could work it hierarchically like the following. This will use the first match:

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Ignore existing files and directories
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

# Set all the rewrites
RewriteRule ^event/(.+)$ event.php?event=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?subj=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks again mate, but for some reason it doesnt seem to work. Ive tried everything, i really dont know whats wrong.

Comment: @robolist see my latest comment to your question :-)

Comment: cheers mate, thanks for all your help. I have now updated my question :)

Comment: @robolist First thing to change is this `RewriteRule ^/event/(.+)$ event.php?event=$1 [L]` to this `RewriteRule ^event/(.+)$ event.php?event=$1 [L]`. This might make a difference but not sure

Comment: @robolist Looking into it :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this would be to link to /event/eventName instead of only /eventName. This way you can put the logic in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/event/(.+)$ event.php?event=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?subj=$1 [L]
```

The [L] here tells that processing should stop after reaching match.

The other way would be to send all requests to index.php?subj= and in index.php have the logic to decide if you need to process it as an event (ie. is there an event with such a name).

Comment: Hi @Clarence, many thanks for trying to help, but for some reason it doesnt seem to work. It messes up the entire site with these rules. But your suggestion to put everything under index.php sounds like the easiest route, although not really how i wanted it. I will give it a go though but would much prefer to handle it all via htacess. :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your 2nd sample has two rewrite rules trying to do catch the same thing (^(.+)$) and send the request to two different places:

```
    RewriteRule **^(.+)$** index.php?subj=$1
    RewriteRule **^(.+)$** event.php?event=$1
```

You need somethin to differentiate them in order for any rule to fire:

```
    RewriteRule **^home/(.+)$** index.php?subj=$1
    RewriteRule **^events/(.+)$** event.php?event=$1
```

OR you need to send the request to a single file/page/handler - a [front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) that can handle the logic for you and present the correct content.

Comment: Hi AMD, many thanks for your help, its not quite doing the job though for some reason. The index rule is working but the second rule still doesnt work.